# Drawing random signal shape in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is it possible in tikz - in a simple way to draw a signal...

I am interested in drawing something like this[image]

The shape of the signal does not matter... I just have to be able to draw the arrows and the text in between.

**Regarding the meta post:**

My intention with this post was never to have someone give me the full solution. I was only interested in possible ways a random signal could be created, which was given by the sine solution ...  I seen now that the title/question might have been misleading. Sorry for the troubles it might have caused you.

Comment: Maybe the `Hobby
package` could help. ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/hobby.pdf

Comment: I would as much as possible like to avoid shaping the wave..

Comment: I would just use a sum of sin waves with different frequency and phase. It will look random :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thats a great Idea!..

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7271/5763

Comment: About the Meta post: that doesn't really have anything to with you, so you don't have to apologize. It's about  how some questions get a lot of upvotes, and others none, even if they both are of the form "how can I do this", with an image. And your post does say that you only want the signal, so it's partly my fault as well, for posting a "full" solution in the first place. However, you could have asked @Dr.ManuelKuehner to post a proper answer, as you seem to have used his suggestion. Neither of the answers use that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pure TikZ solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=16mm,
       every edge/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white,font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
\draw[very thick,red, smooth,domain=9:101] plot (\x/10,rand);

\foreach \x in {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10}
    \draw[dashed]  (\x,-1.1) -- ++ (0,2.2);

\draw   (3.0,-1.3) edge ["Frame step"] ++ (2,0)
        (5.0,-1.3) edge ["Overlap"] ++ (1,0)
        (1.0,-1.6) edge ["Frame 1"] ++ (3,0)
        (5.0,-1.6) edge ["Frame 3"] ++ (3,0)
        (3.0,-1.9) edge ["Frame 2"] ++ (3,0)
        (7.0,-1.9) edge ["Frame 4"] ++ (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah... Nice  ended up with a similar solution.

Answer (score 20):

I'm bored, so here's a suggestion with some help from `pgfplots`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  doublearrow/.style={
    <->, 
    >=latex,
   every node/.style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize}}]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=none,
  clip=false,
  width=12cm,
  height=3cm
]
\pgfmathsetseed{1} % to get same output every time
\addplot[black,smooth,domain=0:10] {rnd};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,3,3.5,5,7,7.5,9}{% draw vertical dotted line at these x-positions
  \draw [densely dotted] (#1,0) -- (#1,1.5);
}

% draw arrows with text
\draw [doublearrow] (1,-0.2) -- node{Frame 1} (3.5,-0.2);
\draw [doublearrow] (3,-0.4) -- node{Frame 2} (5,-0.4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And because I was working on this while other answers were posted, with just TikZ. I've made some macros that hold frame width, step etc., so that you can easily modify if needed. Change one macro, and all the arrows move as well. (I'm assuming the frame width and step are constant here.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  doublearrow/.style={
    <->, 
    >=latex,
   every node/.style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize}}]

\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw plot[smooth,domain=0:12,samples=25] (\x,rnd);

\pgfmathsetmacro\FrameStart{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\FrameW{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\FrameOverlap{0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\FrameStep{\FrameW-\FrameOverlap}

\foreach[
  evaluate=\i as \y using {ifthenelse(mod(\i,2)==0,-0.4,-0.8)},
  evaluate=\i as \X using \i*\FrameStep+\FrameStart,
  count=\j
] \i in {0,...,3} {
  \draw [densely dotted] (\X,0) -- (\X,1.5);
  \draw [densely dotted] (\X+\FrameW,0) -- (\X+\FrameW,1.5);
  \draw [doublearrow] (\X,\y) -- node{Frame \j} (\X+\FrameW,\y);
}
\draw [doublearrow] (\FrameStart+\FrameStep,1.3) -- node{Frame step} +(\FrameStep,0);
\draw [doublearrow] (\FrameStart+3*\FrameStep,1) -- node[above=2pt,font=\tiny]{Overlap} +(\FrameOverlap,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a solution.. 
I think i will go with @ Dr.ManuelKuehner suggestion, and add some sines together...

Comment: @dfh I added one more suggestion, as I was working on it anyway. It's a bit more "automated" than Zarko's.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..  I guess my problem was already resolved @ Dr.ManuelKuehner  comment above. 

From that it was just drawing simple lines.  
Thanks for taking the time doing this though :)

Comment: If the person who downvoted this two hours ago sees this, I would appreciate a comment explaining the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't downvote, but I suspect it may be related to someone finding this question via [this question on Meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/questions-366074-and-questions-366223-i-am-speechless).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That may well be, and I fully understand that people react to the discrepancy/hypocrisy shown in that Meta-question, but that still doesn't justify downvoting both answers to this question within four seconds of each other (I'm guessing here that the same person downvoted Zarko's answer, but I may of course be wrong about that). If my answer is wrong/misleading/terrible, by all means downvote it, but don't downvote an answer because the *question* is bad -- if that was the reason.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I agree with you so I don't know why you're addressing that comment to me :-) I was just trying to help your curiosity

Comment: @ShreevatsaR There was no one else to address it to ... Sorry though, shouldn't have directed that whole rant at you.

Answer (score 1):

I made this solution based on @Dr.ManuelKuehner 's suggestion:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Frame length: 3
        % Overlap length:0.6
        % Frame start sections: 0 - 1.4 - 2.8 - 4.2
        % Frame end sections: 2 - 3.4 - 4.8 - 4.2

        \draw[->]   (-1,0) -- ++ (12,0) node[right] {Time}; %X-axis line
        \draw[thick, blue] plot[domain=0:11.7*pi, samples=60]  (\x/pi,{sin(0.9*\x r) + sin(0.42*\x r)}); %sine wave

        \draw[densely dashed]   (0,-1.5) -- + (0,3.0)      (3,-1.5) -- + (0,3.6);% frame 1 
        \draw[<->]      (0,-1.3) -- node[below] {Frame 1} + (3,0);

        \draw[densely dashed]   (2.4,-1.1) -- + (0,3.3)      (5.4,-1.1) -- + (0,4.1);
        \draw[<->]      (2.4,2.1) -- node[above] {Overlap} + (0.6,0);
        \draw[<->]      (2.4,-2.1) -- node[below] {Frame 2} + (3,0);


        \draw[densely dashed]   (4.8,-1.5) -- + (0,4.4)      (7.8,-1.5) -- + (0,3.6);
        \draw[<->]      (4.8,2.9) -- node[above] {Overlap} + (0.6,0);
        \draw[<->]      (4.8,-1.3) -- node[below] {Frame 3} + (3,0);


        \draw[densely dashed]   (7.2,-1.1) -- + (0,3.3)      (10.2,-1.1) -- + (0,3.3);
        \draw[<->]      (7.2,2.1) -- node[above] {Overlap} + (0.6,0);
        \draw[<->]      (7.2,-2.1) -- node[below] {Frame 4} + (3,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}
```